# Не получается наследовать друзей

Tags: наследование, c++

Здравствуйте!

На сколько я знаю, такое нельзя сделать:

```
class A{
protected:
friend class D;
.....
};

class B : public class A{
.....
};
```

Нужно чтобы class B наследовал эту (friend class D) дружественность.
**Условие такое: в class-е B нельзя писать friend class D;.**
Знаю, что нельзя наследовать дружественность, но если очень нужно, то как-то это можно организовать?

Comment: @Alerr, а Вы уверены, что Вам *действительно нужно* наследовать класс `B` от `A`?

Некоторые гуру говорят, что всегда надо стремиться избегать наследования, заменяя его по возможности композицией.

Впрочем, другие утверждают, что ООП вообще не лучшая идея, а уж C++ просто ужасен.

Comment: @avp, все хорошо к месту и в меру.

Comment: @Alerr

 - Неразрешимость вашей задачи в ее текущей постановке формально следует из стандарта: `[11.4/8] Friendship is neither inherited nor transitive.`

 - Другое дело, что, почти наверняка вам здесь не нужен friendship и, возможно, даже наследование. Покажите ваши классы, опишите, чего вы на самом деле пытаетесь добиться, и вместе что-нибудь придумаем.

Comment: Все просто:
есть класс фигуры, его потомки: прямоугольники, треугольники и прочие... Есть еще некий чужой класс, метод которого вызывается и пытается получить доступ к классам потомкам... Вот и вся идея. Можно, конечно, в каждом потомке писать friend, а можно и сделать запрашиваемые данные public... Но эти варианты не устраивают. Особенно первый.

Answer (score 4):

Уважаемый Котик уже дал ссылку на стандарт.

Но, с другой стороны, если использовать полиморфизм и обращаться к расширенному классу через указатель или ссылку на базовый класс, то можно будет из функции или класса, дружественным базовому, вызвать его метод. А ежели этот метод будет виртуальным и переопределен в расширенном классе, то будет вызван как раз этот метод.

Вот пример.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {   
    friend class D;
    virtual void print () const {
        cout << "AAAA\n";   
    }
};

class D {
    public:
    void say(const A& a) {      
        a.print();  
    }   
};

class B: public   A {
    virtual void print () const {
        cout << "BBBB\n";   
    }   
};

int main() {
    D d;
    B b;
    d.say(b);
}
```

На экран выводится BBBB, т.е. вызывается метод класса B.

Comment: @mikillskegg, Вы уверены, что это как раз то, что хочет ТС?

IMHO ему то надо другое

    Нужно чтобы class B наследовал эту (friend class D) дружественность

т.е., чтобы шла работа с protected полями (методами) базового класса **A**, через методы D, которые видимо ему доступны.

Впрочем, все это больше напоминает гадание на кофейной гуще и головоломки, а не практическое программирование.

Comment: @avp, да тут вообще проблема совершенно надуманная и чисто теоретическая. Хотя и не без интересности.

Comment: Не, проблема не надуманная. Я делаю по сути интерфейс... Нужно чтобы все потомки запросто, без добавления френдов, работали. Чтобы было просто создавать эти потомки. Чтобы человек, просто создал потомка, прописал его характерристики и все. Чтобы не думал об вызовах там сторонних функций(этих тех самых друзей родителя)

Comment: Вот в вашем коде, например, никто из class D; не сможет достучаться до недоступных методов и полей class B без повторного прописания в потомке friend class D; А если потомков ОООчень много. В каждом прописывать? Или делать public то, что не должно быть public.

Comment: @Alerr: Вы должны понимать, что метод на то и private/protected, что его не нужно кому угодно давать в пользование. Если вы хотите в куче классов объявить friend-класс (то есть, нарушить инкапсуляцию), что-то вы делаете не так. Friend-класс должен быть редким-редким исключением.

Comment: Я понимаю что friend это не очень хорошо... С другой стороны, не хочу делать эти переменными public-т.к. в этом случае они станут доступными вообще всем. Придется наверно делать их public.

Comment: @Alerr, Вам же написали, что напрямую это невозможно. Мне кажется, вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 2):

Дружественные классы и функции не наследуются. В каждый класс нужно писать его "друзей" заново. Может, так:

```
class B : public class A{
  .....
public:
  friend class D;
};
```

Comment: Быть может, стоит отказаться от затеи использовать дружественные классы, если один наследует другой?

Comment: Забавный у вас вопрос. То есть логика Страуструпа была такая: вообще дружественность не наследуется, но если ОЧЕНЬ нужно, то это ж совсем другое дело.

Comment: Ну, так вот)